# How to create SharePoint Online sub site with license key

Tags: sharepoint-online, licensing

I have created a subsite in SharePoint online with a lot of functionality and customization. I want to save this site as a template so the client can create a site by using this site template on his environment, but I want to create a license so that a client can use the site for a trial number of days. Then, once the trial is over, they need to enter a license key so that they can use the site more.

Comment: Did you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561539/licensing-system-for-client-side-code-web-application